# Check a radiobutton onload and expand the treeview accordingly using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, treeview, jquery-1.4

I have a treeview which is implemented using jquery **Treeview version 1.4**. TreeView is Implemented as below

```
<div id="container">
   <ul id="outerlist">
      <li>
         <span>level-1</span>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <span>level-2</span>
               <ul>
                  <li>
                     <input type="radio" name="lastnode" value="125" onclick="somefunction()" />
                     <span>lastnodetext</span>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

What i need is ,onload the **lastnode** radiobutton to be checked and all its parent nodes to be expanded (note :there are multiple levels and radiobuttons in the tree).

Below is the code that i have used acheive this

```
$('#container').find(':radio').each(function (index, value) {
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.val() != undefined && $this.val() == "125") {
    $this.attr('checked', 'checked');
    $(this).parents('ul').show();
    return false;
}});
```

This code works perfectly fine in terms of selecting the radiobutton and expanding the level-2 and level-1 nodes. Although the Image (+ or -) does not change. How can i achieve this

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: where is your + / - images?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar  Its at level-1 and level-2

Comment: i recommend you post a jsFiddle of your code

Comment: are you using any CSS class for images? post a jsfiddle link so that we can help you in better way.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Im using "jquery.treeview.js" and "jquery.treeview.css" version 1.4

Comment: please check my answer added in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the **[tree view document](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/)** and found that you just need to add `class="open"` for the `li` which needs to be opened. This will handle all other things like adding images etc.

Also you are doing your operation on single radio button, so don't need to iterate all and then choose your desired one. Instead, use jQuery selector to get only your radio button and do operation on it.

Use below code -

HTML :  add css class to your first level and second level `li`s

```
<div id="container">
   <ul id="outerlist">
      <li class="firstLevel">
         <span>level-1</span>
         <ul>
            <li class="secondLevel">
               <span>level-2</span>
               <ul>
                  <li>
                     <input type="radio" name="lastnode" value="125" onclick="somefunction()" />
                     <span>lastnodetext</span>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery : find first level and second level li to add `open` CSS class to it.

```
var $radio = $('#container input[type="radio"][value="125"]');
$radio.attr('checked',true);
$radio.closest('.firstLevel').addClass('open');
$radio.closest('.secondLevel').addClass('open');
```